# Como obtengo el ID de la URL para actualizar Usuario en Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hola necesito ayuda con esto, Necesito extraer el ID de la url, para poder actualizar el usuario. Cuando termine de actualizar redirigir al login. Nose que mas colocar porfavor ayudenme con esto, se los agradecería mucho. No e encontrado la manera de extraer el ID de la url

Esta es la URL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
<main class="form-signin" >
    
        <form action="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="updateUserIp({ id: /*ACA NECESITO EL ID*/ })">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Bienvenido a Suprapp {{ /*ACA NECESITO EL NOMBRE DEL USUARIO*/ }}</h1>
            <input type="text" id="rut" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="RUT" required="">
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Acceso a la APP</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2020</p>
        </form>
</main>
```

```
  <script>
     import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

     export default {
        computed:{
           ...mapState(['userID','fillUser', 'errorsLaravel']),
           ...mapGetters([])
    },
    methods:{
         ...mapActions(['updateUserIp'])
    }
}
</script>
```

**actions.js**

```
updateUserIp(context, data) {
    context.commit('updateUserIp', data.id)
},
```

**mutations.js**

```
updateUserIp(state, id) {
    var url = urlUser + '/' + id
    axios.put(url, state.fillUser).then(response => {
        state.fillUser = {
            id: '',
            ip_acceso: ''
        }
        state.errorsLaravel = []
    }).catch(error => {
        state.errorsLaravel = error.response.data
    })
},
```

**web.php**

```
Route::ApiResource('userID', 'AccesoController');
```

**AccesoController.php**

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $data = $request->all();
    User::find($id)->update($data);

    return;
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda...

Comment: Podrias enviarlo desde el layout de blade, y recibirlo como props dentro de vue.

Comment: disculpa pero como seria eso?

Comment: Te lo explico debajo.

Answer (score 0):

supongamos que tenemos un controlador, el cual tiene la siguiente funcion index.

```
public function index()
    {
        $layout = currentUser();
        $value = new DateTime();
        $dia = $value->format('Y-m-d');
        $mes = $value->format('m');
        $date = $value->format('Y-m-d');

        $users = User::select('users.*')
                    ->join('user_module','users.id','=','user_module.user_id')
                    ->where('user_module.module_id',2)
                    ->get();

        return view('administration.creditcards.tpcards' ,compact('date','layout','users'));
    }
```

Ahora esto se va al blade, el cual supongamos que recibe lo siguiente, fijate que envio un parametro por la etiqueta del componente para que pueda recibirlo, en este caso global, que recibe desde el back el layout, tu podrias enviar el id o todos los datos que quieras:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    @php
        $global = [
            'layout' => $layout
        ];
    @endphp
    <cards-grilla-ad :global="{{ json_encode($global) }}" :modul="15"></cards-grilla-ad>
@endsection
```

Finalmente, lo recibes por props dentro de vue, de la siguiente manera fijate la linea props.

```
export default {
    props:['global','modul'],
    data() {
        return {
            advance : true,
            min: new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            max: new Date(2049, 11, 31, 24, 0, 0),
            minDate: new Date(1000,1,1),
            maxDate: new Date(2050,9,1),
            searchadvance: true,
```